# Unity: Resolving Android Dependencies freeze. Cannot import any plug-in

Tags: java, android, sdk, unity-game-engine

I have a huge issue. For some reason, I am unable to import almost any plug-in into my Unity project. Whenever the import finishes, I get the Resolving Android Dependencies screen, which never actually resolves the issue. I recently got this issue when I imported the Unity Mediation Plug-in and now I reinstalled my Android Studio, Java and Unity, which resulted in the same error but now even for plug-ins, which worked before. I have no idea what to do. After the reinstall, I had to downgrade my SDK tools to 25.0.5 or I couldn't build the project due to JAVA_HOME error in the Unity Editor. Everything else is up-to-date.

Any help is appreciated. 
[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you imported a plugin, and then this popup appeared and Unity just totally hangs?  That just happened to me, and I'm not sure what to do...

Comment: Yea the same. I have no idea how to fix it. I have been going around different errors for 3 days. My head hurts. I changed Unity version to 5 from 2017 and then the Resolver was fixed, but I couldn't build my APK. Error after error.

Comment: Argh.  I just tried importing some more packages as according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2116) which seems to detail the error we are experiencing, but to no avail.  Do let me know if you've figured this out.

Comment: Hey, I don't know if you managed to fix this, but I seem to have reached a state where I've worked around the error.  I deleted all the GPS and AdMob files from my project, and then reimported GPS and then AdMob whilst Force Resolving the project between each step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well...the problem was that my project folder had spaces in it. If it was
 Test App, it should have been TestApp. When I created my project in Unity (Its my first project) I neglected the name of the Project is used as the folder name too. I understood how the whole engine works inside out in hopeless attempts to fix it, but never did I suspect it was so simple.

Comment: 2019 and we still have to avoid spaces... man! that will never change!

Answer (score 3):

Try going to Edit > Preferences > External Tools > Check/Uncheck the JDK/etc paths and close the window. It can trigger the android dependency manager to continue. If not, go to Assets > External Dependency Manager > Android Resolver > Resolve.

Comment: you saved me today friend

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help or cause more issues -- as I will find out soon I guess, but if you already have Play Services package installed along with the Play Services Resolver that comes with it...when importing the AdMobs package make sure that you uncheck the Play Services Resolver before import since it is already installed. You can manage/update the Play Services Resolver from the Assets menu if needed I believe.

Answer (score 2):

In ProjectSettings you can remove (I suggest rename) the AndroidResolverDependencies.xml then restart unity.
I takes time but you can see jdk working, so wait and it fixes any problem.

Comment: This solved this issued for me when trying to import firebase analytics to unity.
As you suggested, I renamed the file and reopened unity. it opened with some error about gradle. Then I noticed it created a new file with the same name. I saved my scene, restarted and after importing firebase analytics everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check both of the checkboxes I checked under Build Menu and it'll fix.

[image]

Comment: @Deppanshu, with screenshots, please try to add more descriptions too

Answer (score 0):

First of i've downloaded Microsoft's OpenJDK 11
from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/download#openjdk-11
unzipped it, and used it as the JDK folder by selecting:
Preferences -> external tools -> android -> Unchecked JDK installed with unity.
Used the browse button to the above mentioned folder.

Then:
Under project settings -> player - > publishing settings
check both: custom main gradle template
custom gradle properties template